# How to convert bulk of .WAV files into single .CSV files

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, audio, wav

I have to convert 500 .WAV files into one .CSV file. How to convert bulk of .WAV files into one .CSV files in python?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning`, `deep-learning`, `knn`, or `nlp` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Ohh thanks for the info and feedback, I am on it from next time.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to encode each WAV file to Base64 and write it to the CSV file separated by commas. When needed the Base64 encoded CSV has to be decoded again. Python code to encode and decode is below.

```
import base64

file = open("sound1.wav", "rb")
f = open("finalcsv.csv",'w')

byte = file.read(16)
while byte:
    #print(byte)
    base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(byte)
    base64_string = base64_bytes.decode("ascii")

    f.write(base64_string) 
    
    byte = file.read(16)
  


f.close()
file.close()

print("Encoded.")

f = open("finalcsv.csv",'rb')
f1 = open("sound2.wav",'wb')

byte = f.read(24)
while byte:
    #print(byte)
    b1 = base64.b64decode(byte)

    f1.write(b1) 
    
    byte = f.read(24)

f.close()
f1.close()

print("Decoded.")
```

Comment: But I want to give bulk of .WAV files as input and get one .CSV of that all .WAV files as output

Answer (score 0):

Code to take multiple wav as input. I can also give you excel code to take all the wav from a windows folder and embed into a excel sheet (But this cannot be done in a csv file)

```
import base64

wavfiles = ["wav1.wav", "wav2.wav", "wav3.wav"]

fileout = open("csvout.csv",'w')

for wav in wavfiles:
    filein = open(wav, "rb")
    byte = filein.read(16)
    while byte:
        base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(byte)
        base64_string = base64_bytes.decode("ascii")

        fileout.write(base64_string) 
    
        byte = filein.read(16)
    fileout.write(",") 
    filein.close()
    
fileout.close()

print("Encoded.")
```